# What is the correct way to pass training data into a custom openai-gym environment?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am creating a custom [gym environment](http://gym.openai.com/docs/), similar to [this trading one](https://github.com/notadamking/tensortrade/blob/master/tensortrade/environments/trading_environment.py) or [this soccer one](https://github.com/openai/gym-soccer/blob/master/gym_soccer/envs/soccer_env.py). The custom environment is being set up to train a [PPO](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06347.pdf) reinforcement learning model using [stable-baselines](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

My issue is, **the time it takes between batch updates (the time taken to step through the environment and gather rewards) is taking longer and longer and is scaling linearly by about 1-5 seconds every update.** At the beginning this would make sense as the untrained agent "dies" very quickly (`done=True` so the episode ends). As the agent trains it should survive longer, until it starts surviving entire episodes and the time between updates should plateau. But the time between updates continues to increase even after hundreds of updates (hundreds of episodes, tens of thousands of serial steps through the environment). I have monitored training and can see the agent is surviving entire episodes around 50 updates in.

At first I thought that maybe some variable in the environment was persisting and getting very large between updates, slowing the computation time. But when I monitored memory usage during training, it stays constant the entire time. Given that the environment should reset every episode (and initialise all my list variables as empty), increasing variable size shouldn't be an issue in theory.

Having said that, perhaps I am not passing data in correctly into the `MyCustomEnv`. When I read in my entire training dataset into memory (`1e6` samples), I would expect that a batch of only [`n_steps`](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo2.html#stable_baselines.ppo2.PPO2) is passed to the environment at each episode, but I could be wrong (I have set `n_steps=1024`, this is the number of steps in a batch / episode). A minimum code example is below.

```
# myenv.py

import gym
from gym import spaces
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


class MyCustomEnv(gym.Env):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data  # numpy array, shape = (1e6, 5)
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0., high=1., shape=(1, self.data.shape[1]), dtype=np.float32)
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(4)  # 4 actions - see ACTION_LOOKUP below

    def _take_action(self, action):
        my_action = ACTION_LOOKUP[action]
        tmp = do_action(my_action)  # this is a simple function not shown, it returns a float
        self.my_list.append(tmp)

    def _done(self):
        if current_step = self.data.shape[1] - 1:
            return True
        if died():  # another simple function not shown that just checks a running variable
            return True
        return False

    def _next_observation(self):
        obs = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(self.data)[-1]  # last row of numpy array data, scaled
        return obs

    def _reward(self):
        reward = get_reward(self.my_list)
        return reward

    def step(self, action):
        self._take_action(action)
        self.current_step += 1
        obs = self._next_observation()
        reward = self._reward()
        done = self._done()
        return obs, reward, done, {}

    def reset(self):
        self.current_step = 0
        self.my_list = []

ACTION_LOOKUP = {
    0 : "LEFT"
    1 : "RIGHT"
    2 : "UP"
    3 : "DOWN"
}
```

Then when instantiating the environment in my `main` script

```
# main.py

import pandas as pd
from stable_baselines.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines.common.policies import MlpLstmPolicy
from stable_baselines import PPO2

from myenv import MyCustomEnv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv").values  # numpy array
    train_env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: MyCustomEnv(data)])
    model = PPO2(MlpLstmPolicy, train_env, verbose=1)
    model.learn(total_timesteps=int(1e6))
```

Am I doing something wrong here that would cause the time between updates to increase forever? The custom [soccer](https://github.com/openai/gym-soccer/blob/master/gym_soccer/envs/soccer_env.py) environment doesn't seem to pass data into the environment, so maybe there's a better way to have the agent step through an environment of static training data.